# What species of snail is this?

Tags: species-identification, molluscs

I found it in Washington state, in a city south of Seattle. I found it next to a bush after it rained on someone's driveway. Here are two pictures of it:

( originally posted in [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BTShZEMBn4c/) )

[image: Snail photo-1]
[image: Snail photo-2]

If anyone can identify​ this species, kudos to you.

Comment: where is the location?

Comment: @TheLastWord It's in the question…

Comment: If the answer below have answered your query, consider accepting it by clicking the **green checkmark**, giving you and the other user some reputation points. This aids in closing the question as solved. There is no obligation to do it either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It resembles ***[Cepaea nemoralis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_snail)***, or commonly called Grove Snail, belonging to the family **[Helicidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicidae)**.

[image: Snail]

**Image Source**: **[WikiMedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grove_snail,_Lodz(Poland)02(js).jpg)**

According to **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_snail)**, these snails were introduced to North America from Europe. These fascinating creatures occur in diverse forms of shell color as well, as shown below.

[image: Various Shells]

**Image Source**: **[Metodologie di Programmazione](http://naviglimetodologie.blogspot.ca/2014/04/lezione-342014-polimorfismo-e-classe.html)**

Here I have found a very detailed shell and body markers for ***Cepaea nemoralis***.

[image: Identification markers]

**Image Source**: **[ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/236051193_fig3_Figure-1-A-Shell-polymorphism-in-Cepaea-nemoralis-There-is-considerable-phenotypic)**